# EntityFramework code first - account permissions issue

Tags: database, entity-framework, azure, permissions

I am getting started with database development (goal is azure, getting there...). I followed [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) guide to get started with Azure development.

I have successfully:

- created a website in VS2012
- installed azure SDK for .NET
- installed entity framework (EF6alpha) via NuGet
- wrote my first database entities.

When I execute "update-database -ProjectName Models" I receive the error that I lack priveleges (CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database ‘master’).

After a while I read a thread that this might have something to do with privileges. So I tried to run VS as administrator and voila, the database + tables were generated. (maybe that bit might help others looking for a solution for this issue).

But now, back in my development account I still am not allowed to update the database. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wasn't too hard after all.

- start MS SQL Server Management Studio (as administrator)
- open the database you'd like to join
- open the security map
- right click users => add user.
- in the dialog, select windows user and fill in the login name.

done.